# Constexpr class: Inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, constexpr

First of all, I'm working with Clang 3.4.1

I'm writting a global variable which has to serve as a placeholder on compile-time contexts (Primarily as value template parameter). For that purpose, I have written a constexpr class named `chameleon` (It mimics the behaviour of any runtime value):

```
struct chameleon
{
    template<typename T>
    constexpr operator T() const
    {
        return T{};
    }

    constexpr chameleon() = default;
};
```

Since both the conversion operator and the constructor are specified as `constexpr`, I'm able to make instances of that class at compile-time. [For example](https://ideone.com/KhAN6R):

```
template<int foo>
struct bar
{};

using mytype = bar<chameleon{}>;
```

Since this works, and I use it in other places, I decided to write such placeholder type 
just inheriting from `chameleon`:

```
template<std::size_t I>
struct placeholder : public chameleon
{
    using chameleon::chameleon;
};
```

I'm using C++11, so I just used the "new" (C++11 has three years...) inheriting constructors feature.

When declaring the placeholder variable:

```
constexpr const placeholder<0> _1;
```

The compiler rejects the code saying it expects an user-defined default ctor for initialization. So *"Well, inheriting ctors doesn't propagate constexpr, or something like that"* is what I though. Then I changed the using to a default ctor declaration:

```
template<std::size_t I>
struct placeholder : public chameleon
{
    constexpr placeholder() = default;
};
```

Now the compiler says:

> error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const placeholder<0>' requires a user-provided default constructor

If I change the `= default` to a manually defined empty constructor (`constexpr placeholder() {}`) then it works, but the constructor is not evaluated as `constexpr` and the usage of the
`_` placeholder in compile-time contexts is invalid (The common `is not a constant expression` error). The same for manually calling the base ctor.

My question is: **Whats wrong with inheritance and `constexpr`constructors? Is there any way to use inheritance when writting `constexpr` classes?**

**EDIT:** I have a division-by-zero bug, the code using the manually written ctor works perfectly. On the other hand, I don't understand why neither the inheriting constructor or the default constructor declaration worked. The question remains there.

Comment: Compile fine with gcc 4.8.1 (https://ideone.com/wKeJM8).

Comment: @Jarod42 no, it doesn't. Try to use the placeholder: https://ideone.com/Je807r

Comment: Maybe I'm understanding the last part, but I can't reproduce the error on gcc or clang - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89b47cd2d615e731

Comment: I use it and explicitly cast to `int` and it works: https://ideone.com/32pYFp

Comment: Sorry people, was a compile-time division by zero error two hundred of template-errors bellow.... I will delete the question. We really need better tools for debugging template metaprograms...

Comment: But I get the error with clang too :/ (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1453c4e545e8a86f)

Comment: On the other hand, I don't understand why neither the inheriting constructor or the default constructor declaration worked. The question remains there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So "Well, inheriting ctors doesn't propagate constexpr, or something like that" is what I thought

That's not the issue; default and copy/move constructors cannot be inherited. If you don't explicitly define or default them, they'll be implicitly defined following the usual rules.

*§12.9 [class.inhctor]*

> 3      For each non-template constructor in the candidate set of inherited constructors **other than a constructor having no parameters or a copy/move constructor having a single parameter**, a constructor is implicitly declared with the same constructor characteristics unless there is a user-declared constructor with the same
>   signature in the complete class where the *using-declaration* appears or the constructor would be a default, copy, or move constructor for that class. ...
>
> 5      [ *Note:* Default and copy/move constructors may be implicitly declared as specified in 12.1 and 12.8. *—end note* ]

Consequently, `placeholder`, with or without the using declaration for inheriting `chameleon`'s constructors, will have a default constructor implicitly defined, and this constructor will be `constexpr`.

*§12.1/5 [class.ctor]*

> ... If that user-written default constructor would satisfy the requirements of a `constexpr` constructor (7.1.5), the implicitly-defined default constructor is `constexpr`. ...

Your class, with a user provided default constructor, satisfies the requirements in §7.1.5/4 for a `constexpr` constructor. The error you saw was because of the next part.

---

As for why you must provide a constructor definition for a `const` object, let's take a look at your class.

```
struct chameleon
{
    template<typename T>
    constexpr operator T() const
    {
        return T{};
    }

    constexpr chameleon() = default;
};
```

This class is both trivial (9/6) and standard layout (9/7), hence it is a POD (9/10). A POD is uninitialized by default, so a `const` POD without an initializer would be uninitialized, and immutable, making it pretty much worthless (or I'm not able to think of any use cases, at least).

By providing a default constructor, the class is no longer a POD, and will be default initialized.

As @Casey points out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333458/constexpr-class-inheritance#comment37616985_24333884), this requirement is listed in §8.5/7

> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type `T`, `T` shall be a class type with a user-provided default constructor.

Comment: 8.5/7: "If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type `T`, `T` shall be a class type with a user-provided default constructor."