# C++ constexpr inheriting constructor

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, clang++, default-constructor

The following code compiles with GCC 8.2 but not with Clang 6.0.1:

```
// A struct named Foo.
struct Foo
{
  // Data member of type 'int'.
  int val;

  // Default constructor (constexpr).
  constexpr Foo() noexcept : val(0) {}
};

// A struct named Bar.
struct Bar : Foo
{
  // Make use of the constructors declared in Foo.
  using Foo::Foo;

  // A constructor taking an object of type Foo.
  // COMMENTING THIS CONSTRUCTOR SOLVE THE COMPILATION ISSUE.
  constexpr Bar(Foo const obj) noexcept : Foo(obj) {}
};


// A struct named Test.
struct Test
{
  // Data member of type 'Bar'.
  Bar bar;

  // A defaulted default constructor.
  constexpr Test() noexcept = default;
};


// Main function.
int main() { return 0; }
```

Clang fails with the following message:

> error: defaulted definition of default constructor is not constexpr
>   constexpr Test() noexcept = default;

I would like to understand why Clang is rejecting this code.

Comment: You forgot to provide a default constructor to `Bar` (which, however, you're using in `Test`). Providing an argument to `Bar` int `Test()` or alternatively providing a default constructor for `Bar` should both fix the problem. Why however this compiles with G++ I don't understand. (BTW, it doesn't with [**gcc 7.3.0**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mlUjCEuuyLeHMT97) and below)

Comment: @muXXmit2X Possibly C++17 did remove the limitation of not inheriting default constructors (see answer by divinias, "could not find")?

Comment: This is interesting because a [simplified version of this works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ExxTQC7e067YKPW9) you have to go way back to [clang 3.8.1 for this to not work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aRiZw2KPMexOWQBl) ... but adding constexpr into mix breaks the [simplified version](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MbXaTBcVgUo9Oo9C)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like clang is relying on pre C++17 wording from C++14 section [[class.inhctor]p3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.inhctor#3):

> For each non-template constructor in the candidate **set of inherited constructors other than a constructor having no parameters** or a copy/move constructor having a single parameter, a constructor is implicitly declared with the same constructor characteristics unless there is a user-declared constructor with the same signature in the complete class where the using-declaration appears or the constructor would be a default, copy, or move constructor for that class. Similarly, for each constructor template in the candidate set of inherited constructors, a constructor template is implicitly declared with the same constructor characteristics unless there is an equivalent user-declared constructor template ([temp.over.link]) in the complete class where the using-declaration appears. [ Note: Default arguments are not inherited. An exception-specification is implied as specified in [except.spec]. — end note ]

So in C++14:

```
using Foo::Foo;
```

means `Bar` does not inherit `Foo`'s default constructor and `Bar` does not have a default constructor since it is inhibited by your declaration of:

```
constexpr Bar(Foo const obj) noexcept : Foo(obj) {}
```

Adding a default constructor to `Bar` fixes the problem [see it live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yPKrbH33ztsvCklz):

```
constexpr Bar() = default ;
```

The wording was changed in C++17 with the paper [p0136r1: Rewording inheriting constructors (core issue 1941 et al)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0136r1.html) which was can see was accepted from [Changes between C++14 and C++17 DIS](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0636r0.html)

> The **following papers were moved at committee meetings**, but their contents are too specific to call out as separate features: N3922, N4089, N4258, N4261, N4268, N4277, N4285, P0017R1, P0031R0, P0033R1, P0074R0, **P0136R1**, P0250R3, P0270R3, P0283R2, P0296R2, P0418R2, P0503R0, P0509R1, P0513R0, P0516R0, P0517R0, P0558R1, P0599R1, P0607R0, P0612R0

we can see p0136r1 removed `[class.inhctor]`:

> Remove 12.9 class.inhctor, "Inheriting constructors".

I don't see any wording in `p0136r1` that would restrict this case any more. The list of defect reports does not specifically cover this case but the wording changes seem consistent.

So it looks like gcc is correct here and we have a potential clang bug.

#### gcc 7 release notes

We also obtain a diagnostic in gcc pre 7.x ([see it live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/P7Le5luVniIUkJfx)). If we look at the [gcc 7 release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html) we see:

> The **default semantics of inherited constructors has changed in all modes, following P0136. Essentially, overload resolution happens as if calling the inherited constructor directly**, and the compiler fills in construction of the other bases and members as needed. Most uses should not need any changes. The old behavior can be restored with -fno-new-inheriting-ctors, or -fabi-version less than 11.

Which seems to confirm the initial conclusion. If we use `-fno-new-inheriting-ctors` with a slightly modified version of your program [it no longer compiles](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xiPnGu4JxwSPz4TB) which backs up this was changed with `P0136`.

Comment: Seems like a big change and no specific defect report make me wary if this was intended or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have filled a bug report [here](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38673)

Answer (score 5):

In C++14, default constructors can not be inherited.

*§12.9 [class.inhctor]* **(emphasis mine)**

> 3      For each non-template constructor in the candidate set of
>   inherited constructors **other than a constructor having no parameters
>   or a copy/move constructor having a single parameter,** a constructor is
>   implicitly declared with the same constructor characteristics unless
>   there is a user-declared constructor with the same signature in the
>   complete class where the using-declaration appears or the constructor
>   would be a default, copy, or move constructor for that class. ...

This basically means, that for your class Bar, the ctor will be implicitly defined - and means `using Foo::Foo` is not doing anything meaningful.

However, as you are having a separate constructor for Bar, this prevents the implicit definition of a default constructor.

The reason this works when you comment out your separate `constexpr Bar(Foo const obj)` ctor is because of

> 5      [ Note: Default and copy/move constructors may be implicitly
>   declared as specified in 12.1 and 12.8. —end note ]

*§12.1/5 [class.ctor]*

> ... If that user-written default constructor would satisfy the
>   requirements of a constexpr constructor (7.1.5), the
>   implicitly-defined default constructor is constexpr. ...

So, the implicitly declared constructor is declared as constexpr, which makes your code work and compile as expected.

You can remedy the issue by just explicitly defaulting the default ctor like this:

```
constexpr Bar() noexcept = default;
```

You can also take a look at [Constexpr class: Inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333458/constexpr-class-inheritance)

The problem there is a bit different, but very similar to what you are seeing.

Sadly, I am unable to find the relevant parts in the C++17 standard. I assume the reasoning is the same, but can't find the reference to be 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My expectation was indeed that the default constructor would be inherited via the using directive. Looking further into that direction the following answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44522990) suggests that C++17 introduced a change on this specific point. It would be great to get this confirmed.